# Android: PreferenceFragment with custom Preference lifecycle inconsistency?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

I'm trying to create a custom [Preference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html) to be shown in [PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html) as described here: [Building a Custom Preference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Custom). My custom Preference should look and function as [SwitchPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/SwitchPreference.html), but have one additional `TextView` for error reporting.

I got everything implemented and UI looks fine, but I can't initialize this Preference when my PreferenceFragment is shown!

Documentation for `Preference.onBindView()` states that:

> This is a good place to grab references to custom Views in the layout
>   and set properties on them.

So I did:

```
@Override
protected void onBindView(View view) {
    super.onBindView(view);
    txtError = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.error);
}

public void setError(String errorMessage) {
    txtError.setText(errorMessage);
    notifyChanged();
}
```

However, when I call `CustomSwitchPreference.setError(String)` in `PreferenceFragment.onResume()`, I get NPE because `txtError` is null.

I tried to find some workaround, but it looks like there is no lifecycle method in PreferenceFragment which is guaranteed to be called AFTER all the underlying `Preferences` had their `Views` initialized (I checked both `Preference.onBindView(View)` and `Preference.onCreateView(ViewGroup)`).

This behavior doesn't make any sense - there should be some way to initialize UIs of the underlying `Preferences` when `PreferenceFragment` is shown. How can I achieve this?

Note: calls to `customPreference.setTitle(String)` and `customPreference.setSummary(String()` in `CustomPreferenceFragment.onResume()` work fine. It is just the additional `TextView` which I can't grab a reference to...

CustomSwitchPreference.java:

```
public class CustomSwitchPreference extends SwitchPreference {

    private TextView txtError;

    public CustomSwitchPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    public CustomSwitchPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public CustomSwitchPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomSwitchPreference(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
        setLayoutResource(R.layout.custom_switch_preference_layout);
        return super.onCreateView(parent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindView(View view) {
        super.onBindView(view);
        txtError = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.error);
    }

    public void setError(String errorMessage) {
        txtError.setText(errorMessage);
        notifyChanged();
    }

}
```

CustomPreferenceFragment.java:

```
public class CustomPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName(PREFERENCES_FILE_NAME);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.application_settings);
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Preference preference = findPreference("CUSTOM_PREF");
        if (preference == null ||
                !CustomSwitchPreference.class.isAssignableFrom(preference.getClass()))
            throw new RuntimeException("couldn't get a valid reference to custom preference");

        CustomSwitchPreference customPreference = (CustomSwitchPreference) preference;
        customPreference.setError("error");
    }
}
```

custom_switch_preference_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@android:id/widget_frame">

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="3"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/error"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="3"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/widget_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

application_settings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <com.example.settings.CustomSwitchPreference
        android:key="CUSTOM_PREF"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find a proper solution for this issue - this inconsistency feels like a life-cycle bug in AOSP, but I'm not 100% sure about this.

As a workaround, I defined a callback interface that `CustomSwitchPreference` invokes in `onBindView` method in order to notify the containing `PreferenceFragment` that it had been initialized:

```
@Override
protected void onBindView(View view) {
    super.onBindView(view);
    txtError = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.error);
    initializationListener.onInitialized(CustomSwitchPreference.this);
}
```

and all the manipulations on this `CustomSwitchPreference` that I wanted to perform in `onResume` now get performed in `onInitialized` callback. This is an ugly workaround that requires a considerable amount of boilerplate, but it seems to work.